# gradle jar file with yml config file doesn't execute from dockerfile

Tags: java, docker, gradle, dockerfile, build.gradle

I want to run a gradle build inside a container, then execute the jar with its config file and server parameters. This is what I have

```
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app


RUN  chmod +x gradlew  \
  && gradle build

COPY config/*.yml build/libs

RUN cd build/libs \
  && ls -la
  

EXPOSE 8081

ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/app/build/libs/app.jar", "-Dconfig.location=app/build/libs/config.yml", "-Dgrails.env=prod"]
```

I can see that both the yml file and the jar file are in the build libs folder, but when I build the dockerfile, I get error indicating missing yml file. When I reorder them and place config location before the jar file, it finds the config, but doesn't execute the jar file. When I purposely put an incorrect path to jar file, I get an error that jar is not found.

What I get after docker run is

```
    Configuring Spring Security Core ...
... finished configuring Spring Security Core Configuring Spring Security REST 2.0.0.RC1...
... finished configuring Spring Security REST
```

And that's it. Although running locally I get "application running.." aswell.
Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I cannot post a comment as I am a newbie.

I see that you are in build/libs when you run-

```
RUN cd build/libs
```

Then your ENTRYPOINT command is using relative path for config location-

```
"-Dconfig.location=app/build/libs/config.yml"
```

You can try starting the location with "/app" instead of "app".

Also, if that doesn't help, can you paste the exact errors you are getting in the 2 scenarios you mentioned?

Comment: Tried that already, I edited my question with the output of docker run